# DISTILBERT_BASE_UNCASED failed to load - Hugging face transformers

Tags: huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

I am trying to execute :

```py
import ktrain

from ktrain import text

MODEL_NAME='distilbert-base-uncased'

t=text.Transformer(MODEL_NAME, maxlen=500, classes=np.unique(y_train))
```

I am getting the following error:

```
*OSError: Model name 'distilbert-base-uncased' was not found in tokenizers model name list (distilbert-base-uncased, distilbert-base-uncased-distilled-squad, distilbert-base-cased, distilbert-base-cased-distilled-squad, distilbert-base-german-cased, distilbert-base-multilingual-cased). We assumed 'distilbert-base-uncased' was a path, a model identifier, or url to a directory containing vocabulary files named ['vocab.txt'] but couldn't find such vocabulary files at this path or url.*
```

ktrain version 0.14.6
transformers version 2.8.0

Libraries was installed using pip install.

Any help would be appreciated.